# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - Not sure why

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am receiving the above mentioned error when trying to update my database. 
I read about why that might be but I am confused because I have already made the CRUD for 2 other tables in php+javascript so I was just copy pasting and rewriting for the corresponding rows, etc. (And I have already copy-pasted it multiple times to see if i just made a spelling mistake)

Every console log works until that response.json() bit.

```js
// DELETE AND UPDATE SANDWICH

   
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btnDeleteSandwich')){
        const sandwichId = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
        console.log(sandwichId);
        fetch("../backend/api-delete-sandwich.php?id="+ sandwichId, {
            method:'delete'
        })
            .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                document.getElementById('sandwich'+sandwichId).remove();
            })
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains('btnEditSandwich')){
        const sandwichId = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
        let sandwich;
        for (let i = 0; i<allSandwiches.length;i++){
            if (allSandwiches[i].id_sandwich==sandwichId){
                sandwich=allSandwiches[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(sandwich);

// * this is for filling in the update form with existing date but disabled for the moment 
        // const updateName = document.getElementById("updateName");
        // updateName.value = pizza.name;
        // const updatePizzaType = document.getElementById("updatePizzaType");
        // updatePizzaType.value = pizza.type;
        // const updatePizzaIngredients = document.getElementById("updatePizzaIngredients");
        // updatePizzaIngredients.value = pizza.ingredients;
        // const updatePizzaNormalPrice = document.getElementById("updatePizzaNormalPrice");
        // updatePizzaNormalPrice.value = pizza.n_size_price;
        // const updatePizzaLargePrice = document.getElementById("updatePizzaLargePrice");
        // updatePizzaLargePrice.value = pizza.l_size_price;

        document.querySelector('#btnUpdateSandwich').setAttribute('data-id', sandwichId);
        
    }
});

const btnUpdateSandwich = document.querySelector('#btnUpdateSandwich');

btnUpdateSandwich.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const formUpdateSandwich = document.querySelector('#formUpdateSandwich');
    const formUpdateSandwichData = new FormData(formUpdateSandwich);
    const sandwichId = parseInt(btnUpdateSandwich.dataset.id);
    console.log(formUpdateSandwichData);
    console.log(formUpdateSandwich);
    fetch("../backend/api-edit-sandwich.php?id="+ sandwichId, {
            method:'post',
            body:formUpdateSandwichData
        })
        .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
})
```

I'm rather new here so if you need any extra intel to solve the issue, please let me know.

Comment: `../backend/api-edit-sandwich.php` and/or `../backend/api-delete-sandwich.php` returns html/xml and not JSON.

Comment: When this happens to me it's because the server is throwing an error (like 500) but nginx is still sending the content back as-is (which would be, application/json, the original content-type requested, with nginx's 500.html file) and the AJAX code is trying to parse the response as JSON.  Go check your server logs.  PS - this will happen when your Node server defaults every response to be 200, regardless of error.

Comment: Thanks! Ye, it turns out, when getting the data from the front-end, the update form shared the same name/id as the creating form and that is why it caused that error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking to ensure the response is okay and adding a catch to your first promise chain. Your api may be returning an error that isn't being caught. I've updated your example with code from the error handling example as specified in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) for fetch:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (e.target.classList.contains('btnDeleteSandwich')){
    const sandwichId = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
    console.log(sandwichId);
    fetch("../backend/api-delete-sandwich.php?id="+ sandwichId, {
        method:'delete'
    })
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById('sandwich'+sandwichId).remove();
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you were right about it being an api error by my mistake!

Comment: You're welcome! Did my answer help? If so, can you accept it?

Comment: I did but since it's a new account, I need 15 reputation before my likes, acceptances are publicly shown

Comment: Got it! Thank you.